# Find multiple order-statistics of an array

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, search-algorithms

Given array $a$ of size $n$ and array $p$ of size $m$. How we can for every $i < m$ find $p_i$-th order statistics of array $a$ in $O(m log(n) + n)$?

We can find order statistics separately, but it will be $O(mn)$. How can we do better?

Comment: (I have an inkling what kind of data structure you may have recently been introduced to.)

Answer (score 1):

We would need to choose a tree data structure that preprocesses $n$ elements in $O(n)$ and processes each of the $m$ order-statistics queries in $O(log\ n)$, leading to a complexity of $O(m\ log\ n + n)$. Notice when $m > n$, this will be less optimal than a static $O(n\ log\ n)$ solution.